# fetch from database and display in input fields

Tags: php, jquery, ajax

I have a 7 check-boxes(monday,tuesday,wed,thur,friday,sat,sunday) and each of these tag i am having start and end time tag. Down below you can see the picture of the design

[image: HERE IS THE DESIGN]

Now in database there is couple of entries like 1st id is having monday and bluh..bluh. You can see the picture of the database

```
<form  id="checking" method="POST" >
        <?php   
        $data=new User();
        // in row it is array of the database details
        $row=$data->Display('date');

    $checkbox='';
    $days = ["","Monday","Tuesday","Wednesday","Thursday","Friday","Saturday","Sunday"];
    $out[]='<table>';
        for($i = 1; $i <=7; $i++){
            $out[]= '<tr>';
            $out[]= '<td><input type="checkbox" name="events[]" value="'.$i.'" />'.$days[$i].'</td>';
            $out[]= '<td><input type="text" name="start'.$i.'" value="'.$row[$i]['starttime'].'" />da</td>';
            $out[]= '<td><input type="text" name="end'.$i.'" id="endTime'.$i.'" />End Time</td>';
            $out[]= '</tr>';
        }
        $out[]='<table>';
        echo join($out);
?>
       <br/> <button  id="sub"  name="btnregister">Submit</button>      
        </form>
```

[image: DATABASE PICTURE]

Now here is the trick- Fetch the details from the database and display it in input fields and if monday is having then it should checked that checkbox.

I really do not know what type of code i write and how i can print weekend name and should checked the checkbox if enteries is entered in database.

Comment: we need to see code examples of what you've tried so far to help you

Comment: first you try it and show us code what you done?

Comment: @MohitKumar I really do not know how i do it. I  can display the data in input field but how it will know that monday value should only enter in monday

Comment: Check [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16239663/php-checkbox-set-to-check-based-on-database-value) or [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18472510/checking-checkboxes-from-database-values) for some examples .

Comment: @Swati So when i will fetch the data from database then how it will know that it should go on which input tag

Comment: When hit this page url i should see the enteries of  database in these input tag

Comment: this is your insert page , where you want to see it in view or edit page?

Comment: @MohitKumar I have a data in database and i have to fetch in these fields and if rechange that then on click it should update

Answer (score 0):

***Hope this will helps you...***

```
<?php
// Create connection
$con=mysqli_connect("hostname","username","pass","dbname");

$result = mysqli_query($con,"SELECT * FROM table_name"); 
while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result))
  {
    $a=$row['field_name'];

?>
<input type="checkbox" name="week[]" value="monday" <?php if(in_array("monday",$a)) { ?> checked="checked" <?php } ?> >
<input type="checkbox" name="week[]" value="tuesday" <?php if(in_array("tuesday",$a)) { ?> checked="checked" <?php } ?> >
<input type="checkbox" name="week[]" value="Wednesday" <?php if(in_array("Wednesday",$a)) { ?> checked="checked" <?php
 } ?> >
<?php
}
?>
```

Comment: what is field_name

Comment: field_name is colum name which you want ?

Comment: See the question carefully. I want to print Monday Tuesday....go on then in database it will checked which is having in database same for the text tags.... Here is the problem how should print weekend name with your code